# Symfony messenger set prefetch_count for rabbitmq

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq, messenger

It is possible set option "prefetch_count"in symfony messenger?
I migrate from RabbitMqBundle to Symfony Messenger and not see this option.

RabbitMqBundle can configre it like below

```
consumers:
    upload_picture:
        connection:       default
        exchange_options: {name: 'upload-picture', type: direct}
        queue_options:    {name: 'upload-picture'}
        callback:         upload_picture_service
        qos_options:      {prefetch_size: 0, prefetch_count: 1, global: false}
```

But how to set prefetch_count in messenger.yml ?

Comment: OK, Its not possible but symfony get one by one message like prefetch_count: 1
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/47160